# How should very large sample sizes be used?

Tags: distributions, survey-sampling, census

At what point can very large samples, as a proportion of the population, be treated as a census? For example, if your sample contains 90% of the population units, can one dispense with inferential statistical inferences?  What about 80%? And so on . . ..

Comment: Consider looking at this previous question and answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/when-the-population-has-a-known-fixed-size-are-tables-for-the-t-statistic-wrong.  This concept should generalize to any near census tests.

Comment: I think it depends on how you define "population". By "population", if you mean a collection of observations that can never be sampled again (representing the universe of obs in its entirity), then yes you could use a finite population correction factor to shrink the stnd error on sample estimates as n approaches N. However if your "population" can be considered a random sample from a much larger theoretical population of observations, then inferential statistics still apply without an fpc.

Comment: It depends. In the US there is a decennial political debate about whether the Bureau of the Census can be allowed to use statistical sampling procedures to make estimates, rather than attempting to perform a complete census. The argument against attempting a census is that the bias introduced by nonresponse and other missing information, even with a 99+% census, is too large to be ignored. In general some questions cannot be answered without a 100% census, such as "what is the largest value in the population?"

Comment: @whuber, maybe we shouldn't be asking questions that cant be answered by sampling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When the population has a known fixed size, are tables for the t statistic wrong?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/when-the-population-has-a-known-fixed-size-are-tables-for-the-t-statistic-wrong)